# displaying the optimised structure

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct _octet
{
char tft_op:3;
char e_bit:1;
char no_of_pkt:4;
}octet_t;

int main()
{
octet_t st_octet;
st_octet.tft_op = 0x8;
st_octet.e_bit = 0x1;
st_octet.no_of_pkt = 0x10;
char *ptr = (char*)&st_octet;
printf("%#x\n",*ptr);
return 0;
}
```

here i want to store 3 bits in tft_op,  1  bit e_bit, 4 bits in no_of_pkt, but i want the o/p as a combined 1 byte i.e is want the o/p as FA but the o/p i get is 0x8 what should i do to get the o/p as FA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values are too big for the allocated space:

```
0x8 = 1000b - four bits, not three
0x1 = 1b - but if char is signed you can only have 0 and -1!
0x10 = 16 = 10000b - five bits, you'be allocated four
```

So, the effective result is:

```
(0x8 | (0x1 << 3) | (0x10 << 4)) & 0xff

=> (0x8 | 0x8 | 0x100) & 0xff

=> 0x8
```

which is what you're getting. 0xfa is:

```
11111010b
```

but you assume that the first item in the structure is at bit position 7 (the most significant) but the standard (as far as I know) doesn't specify where the bits should start (it could be bit0, the least significant) and looking at your output I guess the first field is the least significant bit, so you have:

```
ccccbaaa
```

where a is tft_op, b is e_bit and c is no_of_pkt. To get 0xfa it's either:

```
tft_op = 2
e_bit = 1
no_of_pkt = 15
```

or, if the order is the other way round:

```
tft_op = 7
e_bit = 1
no_of_pkt = 10
```

Also, rather than doing `char *ptr = (char*)&st_octet;` look into using a union:

```
typedef union
{
  struct _octet
  {
    char tft_op:3;
    char e_bit:1;
    char no_of_pkt:4;
  };
  char data;
} octet_t;
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, bit fields are poorly defined in C and should be avoided if possible. Due to memory padding, endianness etc. it is hard to tell how the bits will be aligned in memory. But to adress some specifics of your code:

First of all you have to change the structure members to `unsigned char` or `unsigned int`, otherwise you will loose one bit for representing the sign.
The `tft_op`-member is only three bits wide, but you try to assign a value which requires 4 bits (0x8 = 0b1000). It ends up being assigned three zeros in memory (on this machine anyway, this again will depend on the endianness etc). It successfully sets the `e_bit` to 1. The `no_of_pkt` has the same problem as `tft_op`, 0x10 (=0b10000) needs five bits, but the field is only 4 bits wide. Hence that member is assigned zeros. In the end your bit field looks like this: `000:1:0000`, or `0001000`, or `0x8`.

Comment: then how can i store this value. i want to store 
tft_op = 111; e_bit = 0; no_of_pkt = 1000 i have to input some thing like this how can i do this, constrain is that i cannot use the entire char as the data should be of this form 11111000 when i o/p o want 11111000 as o/p in hexa equivalent

Comment: If you want `tft_op` to be 111 in binary, assign it the hexadecimal value 0x7, and to the same thing for the other members of the struct. You should also change the members of your struct to `unsigned char`, or `unsigned int`. As it is now the member `e_bit` can only hold the values 0 and -1, as Skizz pointed out below.

Answer (score 0):

st_octet.tft_op = 0x8;  // out of range, max is 7

st_octet.no_of_pkt = 0x10;   // out of range, max is 0xF

The program is correct, values are incorrect.